# React live data fetching on multiple occasions

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to upgrade my app updating state when the prices of the currencies in the API change, as of now, I am doing a single API call on request but I want the app to update live when the price of the API change, I thought of using a setTimeout and doing the API call multiple times but that will eventually make performance go down and memory will start to fill up, on the other hand, not all of the keys within the API call are changing, as name or ID, so I don't need to whole information stored every time, how would I manage to do this?  Thanks!

````
 function CENTRAL_HUB() {
    const API_URL =
        'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false';
    const [coins, setCoins] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(API_URL)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
            setCoins(res.data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }, []); ```
````

Comment: You will have to recall using setInterval. The only other way is if the the api has a socket connection you can subscribe to.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution - there is an npm package, [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron), that allows you to execute a function whenever your scheduled job triggers.